# Cannot assign "<User: kdkd@gmail.com>": "Movie.owner" must be a "Suppliers" instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to assign an owner as an object and I must be doing it wrong because it is still raising

```
Cannot assign "<User: kdkd@gmail.com>": "Movie.owner" must be a "Suppliers" instance.
```

Request Method: POST

This is my serializer for my Movie model.

```
class MovieTicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['owner', 'title', 'price', 'date', 'description', 'seat', 'choice', 'active']

def create(self, validated_data):
    owner = self.context['request'].user
    movie = Movie.objects.create(owner=owner, active=True, **validated_data)
    return movie
```

And this is the View

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated, ])
def movie_ticket_detail(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = MoveTicketSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            ticket = serializer.save()
            data['request'] = ' ticket is instantiated '
            data['title'] = ticket.title
            data['owner'] = ticket.owner
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
        return Response(data)

class TicketModel(models.Model):
owner = models.ForeignKey(Suppliers, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='TICKET')
price = models.IntegerField()
date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
description = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=False)
posted = models.DateTimeField(default=now, editable=False)
active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Meta:
    abstract = True


class Movie(TicketModel):
    seat = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    choice = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_OF_MOVIES_CONCERT_OTHERS, default=1)

    def __repr__(self):
        return {'title': self.title, 'price': self.price, 'description': self.description, 'date': self.date}
```

Comment: post your models also

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    owner = Suppliers.objects.get(email=self.context['request'].user)
    movie = Movie.objects.create(owner=owner, active=True, **validated_data)
    return HttpResponse(movie, content_type="text/json-comment-filtered")
```

is there something wrong with implementing it like this. it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can not return model instances or queryet instead you need to return native python data type in the format json, xml or other content types. First Create Serialzier

```
 class SupplierSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Supplier
            fields = '__all__' # Or sepecific fields ['id','name']
```

Then Use serializer as below.

```
# you need to get Supplier object 
supplier_obj = get_object_or_404(Supplier,user=ticket.owner)
data['owner'] = SupplierSerializer(supplier_obj).data
```

OR

```
supplier_obj = get_object_or_404(Supplier,user=ticket.owner)

data['owner'] = supplier_obj.id # just return id
```

Comment: does this mean I have to implement Model.save(commit=False)?  and supplier_obj,  would I need to create this function? because it's throwing me an error that the function doesn't exist

Comment: @ExodusTesfaye you need to get object first see the updated answer

Comment: @ExodusTesfaye please mark as correct answer if it solves thank you